# Problem with Cursor

Tags: java, android, cursor

I am trying to pass a Cursor to a method. But i am getting this error.

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable c inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

the code.

```
public void loggedin(String title, String message, String positive, Cursor c) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            HomeActivity.this);
    alertbox.setTitle(title);
    alertbox.setMessage(message);
    alertbox.setPositiveButton(positive,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String username = c.getString(0);
                    MessagingApplication.setUsername("");
                    String currentUserName=MessagingApplication.getUsername();
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, currentUserName, 5);

                    alertbox("Error", currentUserName,
                            "Back", null);

                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                            MailActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(i);
                }
            });

    alertbox.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OnClickListener is an anonymous inner class. You can't use non-final variables with scope outside of the anonymous inner class.

This is because an anonymous inner class gets a copy of all local variables so they will be available when the inner class is used. If the variable wasn't marked final, there is no guarantee that the value would be the same.

So you need to declare your cursor as final:

```
public void loggedin(String title, String message, String positive, final Cursor c) {
```